# RLS Algorithm (Memoryless)

Tags: adaptive-filters, least-squares, adaptive-algorithms

I have been studying the adaptive filters lately and now when I am at RLS (Recursive Least Squar) Algorithm I came across the term used in the weighting function of the RLS called forgetting factor ($\lambda$). This term ‘memoryless’ itself confuses me. My doubt is:

- How is memoryless RLS different than the standard RLS? Does it involve some specific value for lambda (as in, it is said that if $\lambda$ $= 1$, system has infinite memory).

I would be glad if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its bare classical form the RLS algorithm, recursively (for every new iteration), solves the classical problem of least squares; by computing the optimal FIR transversal filter coefficients $w[n]$ which minimizes the sum of error squares between the produced filter output $y[n]$ and a desired response $d[n]$ where the error sum is based on the entire data set beginning from the first sample $y[0]$ to the last sample (the current sample) $y[n]$. Therefore as time progresses, $n \to \infty$, the range of data set also goes to infinity, which means that the **memory** of the algorithm is infinite; i.e., the current value of the output $y[n]$ and the FIR coefficients $w[n]$ depend (indirectly via recursion) on the entire sample set.

A consequence of the infinite memory is that the **estmation** becomes more and more exact and refined given that the inputs were WSS random process. On the other hand a clear drawback of this infinite memory dependency is the fact that if the inputs are not WSS then the filter response to reflect the new conditions is **slow** (the entire past which is irrelevant to the current computation still effects the output due to infinite memory) and **tracking** is lost.

In order to improve this last situation, and therefore to make the algorithm track non stationary inputs, its memory should be shortened; i.e., only a finite amount of last local samples should effect the current computations. This is achieved by a **forgetting** factor $\lambda$ embedded into the recursion equations. The range of $\lambda$ is between $0$ and $1$ where $\lambda = 1$ converts the algorithm to classical form with infinite memory with no tracking and $\lambda \to 0$ has less and less memory and more responsive with better tracking...

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. I was confused in the term 'memory-less' which now if I understood correctly doesnt mean 'memory-less' but 'less-memory' because as $\lambda$ can't be zero (because of its presence in the denominator of the $\Psi^{-1}$) we can not get rid of it. Also, I think that we can make $\lambda$ even smaller and it with the past values of the coefficients fades away quickly.

Comment: Yes; the smaller the forgetting factor $\lambda$ the faster the past values will fade away, hence the shorter will be the memory of the filter... Note that the term **memory** does not refer to the physical storage space (as registers of a digital filter etc) but the **effect** of past values on the present.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks a lot @Fat32.